# How to filter data in datagridview if I want to search for a specific name, team which it belongs to (combobox), gender and activity?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Let's say I have 5 members in my database and member 1 is male who is active and belongs to team Lakers, member 2 is female who is inactive and belongs also to team Lakers, member 3 is female who is active and belongs to team Houston, member 4 is male who belongs to team Houston. How can I filter data so if I click male the datagridview is gonna show all male members, if I click male and active the datagridview is gonna show all active male members if I type in name in textbox David and select team Lakers and I check radiobutton Male to show only that member in datagridview? Code below is what I accomplished so far.

Here you can see design of the filter I'm trying to do.

[image]

```
 private void Filtriraj_clanove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (baza_filter_clanova.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("ime LIKE '{0}%' OR prezime LIKE '{0}%'", pretraga_ime_prezime.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using MySQL for database. :)

Comment: What is the result? It's not filtering at all? What is in pretraga_ime_prezime.Text?

Comment: @Jon It's filtering when I type in name or surname. pretraga_ime_prezime.Text is the textbox where I'm typing in name or surname and when clicking button Filtriraj članove it filters the data in datagridview.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I want to make when I type in name and select from combobox Sekcija and check radiobutton Aktivan that it filters only users with that name that are active and are in selected Sekcija. If it makes sense. @Jon

Comment: Please see my answer below, and excuse if it's not 100% correct as I don't speak your language so I don't fully understand some of the words in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, where you can build up a Filter Expression for the RowFilter using all the properties you want to filter on (name, gender, status)

```
private void Filtriraj_clanove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read name/gender/status from the UI
    var name = pretraga_ime_prezime.Text;
    var sekcija = cmbSekcija.Text;
    var active = optStatus.SelectedIndex == 0 ? true : false; // True for active, False for inactive

    // Get datasource
    var dtSource = baza_filter_clanova.DataSource as DataTable;

    var sbFilter = new StringBuilder();
    // Filter name
    sbFilter.AppendLine($"(ime LIKE '{name}%' OR prezime LIKE '{name}%') AND ");
    // Filter active
    sbFilter.AppendLine($"(status = '{active}') AND ");
    // Filter male/female
    sbFilter.AppendLine($"(sekcija = '{sekcija}') ");

    // Apply row filters
    dtSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = sbFilter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Okay, I like the solution even tho I haven't had time to try it yet, but if I have data in combobox Sekcija (dancers A group, dancers B group, musicians A group, musicians B group, etc.) and I want to search member by name David and he belongs to Sekcija dancers A group, male and he's active member in that community how would I solve that problem? @Jon

Comment: Furthermore, if I have 10 members in database and they all have same name, but different last name and I want to check which one of those are active how could I accomplish that? Or what are active members in let's say dancers A group sekcija? How to do that? Any idea? I was thinking of if commands but not sure how would that work.